# On gravitational quantum tunnelling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, spacetime, quantum-tunneling

All celestial bodies have a [gravitational well](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_well), and particle in the vicinity of this well would feel a gravitational force. My questions are:

a)How can I find the thickness of such a gravitational well?

b)Shouldn't  the subatomic particles, e.g. An electron be confined to the potential well of a planet or a star?

c)Is quantum mechanical tunnelling a possibility for the electron (here) to get over the potential barrier?

> E.g.: A black hole of infinite mass in the presence of another body becomes completely transparent quantum mechanically ( $\Pi$ = 1). But in an [Aharonov-Bohm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect)-like effect, if we consider two systems, each with black hole (B.H.) and concentric shell, opposite each other can result in a tunneling probability, $\Pi$ greater than 0.

In a simplified model of a black hole facing a body of mass $M_{2}$. $M_{2}$ is centered at $R$ opposite a black hole of mass $M$ centered at the origin. Since tunneling is greatest near the top of the barrier, the deviation from a $\frac{1}{r}$ potential toward the center of each body is not critical. The potentials used are that of two point masses, so $M_{2}$ may also be a black hole. Thus two little black holes may get quite close for maximum tunneling radiation. Solving the Schrödinger equation outside the black hole:

> $$-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}{D^{2}\psi}=-\left[\frac{-GmM}{r}+\left(-\frac{GmM_{2}}{R-r}\right)-E\right]\psi$$
>   In the region $a\leq r\leq b$, where $a$ bad $b$ are classical turning points, and $$E=-\frac{GmM}{a}+\left(\frac{-GmM}{R-a}\right)=-\frac{GmM}{b}+\left(\frac{-GmM_{2}}{R-b}\right)$$
>   Since, $T=e^{-2\Delta \gamma}$, 
>   $$\Delta \gamma=\frac{m}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{d}}\left[\sqrt{b(b-d)}-\sqrt{a(a-d)}-dln\left|\frac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{b-d}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a-d}}\right|\right]$$
>   Here $d=\frac{Ma(R-a)R}{[M((R-a)R+M_{2}a^{2}]}$ and for  $R>>b$ & $M_{2}>>M$

Thus, $\Delta \gamma$ approaches zero as $a$ approaches $b$, yielding $\Pi$ approaches 1. When $M$ approaches zero, or $M_{2}$ approaches infinity, or equivalently $\frac{M}{M_{2}}$ approaches zero, $\Delta \gamma$ approaches zero and $\Pi$ approaches one. Hence observing quantum tunnelling.

For a better detailed derivation refer [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0212249.pdf)

Comment: Naveen,  I mean no offence to you in any way, but changing the question after an answer has been posted is not really the proper way to ask it.

Comment: @CountTo10 I have first asked you what I added to the question(as an edit) in the comment section under your answer. I hope I didn't offend you and disrespect your answer in any way, my apologies. I am going to edit my question again, but am not adding any new subquestion, just going to mathematically  represent what I have highlighted in my question; just wanted to let you know before I do it.

Comment: No offence taken, I want us both  to learn more about the topic, which is the most important thing. But **other people** might be annoyed if they don't see the full question first ( I honestly don't mind about rep points or things like that), if they feel you don't ask the full question in one go. If you look at the meta posts you might see what I mean. Anyway, all the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Quantum tunneling enables the penetration of a particle through a potential barrier without the expenditure of energy. It requires that you have the same energy available on both sides of the barrier. In the gravitational "potential well" there is no potential barrier that can be penetrated. Even at infinity the potential is higher than any energy state in the interior of the well.

A gravitational potential barrier exists between two close celestial bodies, like between the moon and the earth. However, these barriers are so extremely thick that a tunneling probability for a subatomic particle can be excluded.

However, a subatomic particle, like an electron, can, due to its low mass, acquire such a high thermal velocity, the escape velocity $$v=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$$ that it can (classically) leave the potential well of a celestial body. For the earth at sea level the escape velocity is $11.2km/s$. The mean thermal velocity of an electron at room temperature is $75km/s$. Thus an electron with mean thermal velocity, if uninhibited,  would classically leave the potential well of the earth.

Comment: But what if there are two black holes next to each other, this can result in a tunnelling probability greater than 0. Thanks!

Comment: +1 but I think we ended up answering different questions :). Anyway, Wikipedia has this line about energy _In quantum mechanics, these particles can, with a very small probability, tunnel to the other side, thus crossing the barrier. Here, the "ball" could, in a sense, borrow energy from its surroundings to tunnel through the wall or "roll over the hill", paying it back by making the reflected electrons more energetic than they otherwise would have been_ but in your answer you say _without expenditure of energy_.  Should it really be, without using **extra** energy? Regards

Comment: @CountTo10 - Explanations of  tunneling using the uncertainty between energy and time are only heuristic. When you solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation for a simple square barrier tunneling problem, you  *a priori* assume wave solutions corresponding to a *fixed energy below the barrier height* and obtain reflection and transmission probabilities for the waves.  The wave solutions in the barrier are purely damped exponentials. Regards..

Comment: @Naveen Balaji - when you have two celestial bodies next to each other you have classically a potential barrier that can always be tunneled through. However, depending on the height and width of the barrier and the mass of the particle such a probability is mostly astronomically small. When two black holes are close you must in any case use GR to treat this problem and it is known that GR has until now not been unified with quantum mechanics.

Comment: @freecharly  thanks for coming back so quick.  I can math-wise  solve all the standard first year potential wells,  Dirac combs etc , but I never **thought** about them as much as I should have,  I just did the math . There is an old book by David Bohm that treads a fine line between the math and the assumptions we have to make. Its the only textbook I have seen that tries to say **why** as well as **how**.

Comment: @CountTo10 - I know the book by Bohm. It still is an excellent textbook to understand the foundations of standard quantum mechanics. It does not contain the famous alternative Bohm interpretation of quantum mechanics. But I read that when Bohm wrote this textbook he thought so deeply about the foundations of quantum theory that he finally came up with his alternative theory.

Comment: @freecharly no, he does not use Dirac notation and he does not push in any way his pilot wave, / hidden variables idea, but  as you say, he might have come up with that later, and this book was written before the  Bell inequality came along. The depth of his thinking is reflected in the fact that there is nearly as much text as math.

Comment: @freecharly thanks for that. You mentioned that the case of two BH's close to each other must be treated with GR, but in the paper link I have given in my question, the case is treated with QM and the probability of tunnelling is found hence. So would that treatment be wrong, if yes then how could such a system be handled?

Comment: @Naveen Balaji - If the classical gravitation potentials are assumed to be correct, then you can use these potentials in the Schroedinger equation to calculate the tunneling.

Comment: @freecharly If the use of gravitational potential in the Schrödinger equation is a correct approach, then why worry the problem with GR(I ask as I fail to see the connection)? Could you please send me a link to some paper where GR is used to address QM tunnelling.

Comment: @Naveen Balaji - Sorry, I don't know any paper on QM tunneling in connection with GR. The problem is that in GR gravity is not a force with a potential. But perhaps in special situations it can be equivalently viewed that way. The Schrödinger equation can always be used when you have a potential energy for your particle.

Answer (score 2):

I was asking myself the same question. Upon further thinking I had concluded that yes it should be possible for an object to tunnel 'out' of such a gravity potential.

As others have pointed out, the gravitational potential well is not a super well defined well. The potential energy increases non-linearly to distance. But this should not mean that tunnelling it is not possible.

One could just simplify the problem into a 2-dimensional gravitational force vs distance problem. In this case the gravitational attractive force must be defined as a function of distance. A Hamiltonian can then be constructed to represent the potential energy of the objects as a function of distance. A particle-like localised wavefunction representing the probability of the particle being found can then be appropriately defined. Then, to see what happens to such a particle over time, one can plot the wavefunction over a range of time (present to future) by letting it evolve over time according to the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the thickness of such a gravitational well?

Theoretically you shouldn't, the effect of the mass should propagate for ever. Practically, it depends on how sensitive your measuring instruments are.

> Shouldn't the subatomic particles, e.g. An electron be confined to the potential well of a planet or a star?

Why? You refer yourself in your title to quantum tunnelling, which is usually used in connection  with electromagnetic forces, but it's  not exclusively confined to that force. Although, the heavier the mass, the less likely you are to find a particle relatively far away from it. But I think you might be mixing up electrostatic and gravitational wells when you use the word tunnelling in the context of this question.

> If there is a well defined thickness, then is tunnelling a possibility for the electron (here) to get over the potential barrier?

There is no abrupt cut off point in these situations. No well defined thickness is involved. Again, I would not see it in conventional tunnelling terms.

Comment: So would the particles inside the gravitational well not feel the influence of the potential? Also could you please explain a little more on why there must be no thickness associated to the gravitational well.

Comment: Sure, take the Sun. We can detect the influence of it all the way to the edges of the solar system, it's just that it get weaker, but because a gravity source potentially is infinite in distance, ( since gravitons are massless), it should be felt for ever. Look up the LIGO experiments on Wikipedia to see how weak, but also how far, gravitational effects can be felt. A thickness implies is a wall, with a well defined boundary, but forces such as electromagnetism, ( we can see galaxies a long, long way from us) and gravity do not act as if they have thickness, like a material object has.

Comment: A black hole of infinite mass in the presence of another body
becomes completely transparent quantum mechanically ( Π = 1). But in an [Aharonov-Bohm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov–Bohm_effect)-like effect, if we consider two systems, each with black hole (B.H.) and concentric shell, opposite each other can result in a tunneling probability, Π greater than 0. Thanks!

Comment: @Naveen Balaji - A black hole doesn't have an *"infinite mass"*. Also, this is not necessary. The problem is more that you have to consider two close black holes in the framework of General Relativity which doesn't attribute a potential or force to gravitation. Whether there is something similar in GR to a potential barrier that can be tunneled through is *prima facie* not clear.